# JasperReports Continued on next page Grouping

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a jasperreport that prints debtors statements. I need to print 'Continued on the next page' in place of my existing group footer when there are more records than can fit on the first page.

I have created a second group footer which has the message and I want to print this when there is more to print, and the existing when it has finished.

Is there a way I can tell, at the end of the page, if there are more records in the group to print so I can build a "Print with Expression" expression?

With thanks

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is the way I solved this.

I moved my subtotals for each client to the Page Footer and I added a text field with the words 'Continued...'.

In my group footer I placed a subreport component. I created a Boolean var called returnValue and passed it to and back from the subreport which set it false.

Using the print expression I only print the subtotal fields when returnValue is false and the 'Continue...' field when it tests null.